# Rational Functional tester manual verification points title doesn't appear in the log

Tags: rft

I'm using a manual verification point - it works well - but when it appears in the log its name -or title- appears empty, what should i do to make the manual VP's title appears in the log, thanks in advance 
Abed.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
vpManual("Your VP name here", expectedData, actualData).performTest();
```

The VP name should not contain spaces, dots or other "strange" characters, keep on letters, digits and underscore _

If you use a string variable for the name, **check it is not null or empty**.
Also note the name must be unique in the script. If you provide a little example of your problem I can try answering with more details.

[Take a look at the RFT docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.rational.test.ft.api.help/ApiReference/com/rational/test/ft/script/RationalTestScript.html#vpManual%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks for your response,
`IFtVerificationPoint categoryHeaderVP = vpManual("categoryHeaderVP", dpString("subCategoryName"), mainCategoryHeader().getProperty("text").toString());
    categoryHeaderVP.performTest();`
i have used the precede code but the name of the VP doesn't appear in the log, as other VP.

Comment: Your code is correct. Try to contact IBM support. Wich language did you install RFT with? I found it has some little translation issues when working with languages different from english, so I would recommend to try it in english. It may be some bug with the Log resources in foreign languages.